# Getting a MAX_MEMBERS_EXCEEDED error when adding users

Tags: docusignapi

I am getting the following error trying to add users to my `DocuSign` account via the API.  Any suggestions? Code below.

```
<newUsersSummary xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<newUsers><newUser><errorDetails><errorCode>MAX_MEMBERS_EXCEEDED</errorCode>
<message>The maximum number of members for the account has been exceeded.</message></errorDetails>
</newUser></newUsers></newUsersSummary>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a maximum number of users set on your account and it needs to be increased. Please contact your Account Manager.